# Neos extension repository

Tags: neoscms

I'm starting with Neos.

Is there any extension repository for Neos as for TYPO3 CMS?

Or some tutorial on how to upgrade a TYPO3 (Extbase/Fluid) extension to Neos (Flow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not yet any TYPO3 Neos Extension repository. Instead you can use http://packagist.org/ and search for typo3 or neos.

If a Neos "extension repository" will ever be available, it will probably be a subset of packagist packages anyway.

You could also check out git.typo3.org and search for repositories starting with Packages/

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon this. By now, there is an official package repo which can be found under https://www.neos.io/download-and-extend/packages.html. It's still a flat list, but can be searched and will soon be filterable and such.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official extensions repository currently.

Since Typo3 Neos is not a replacement for Typo3 CMS there is no upgrade path as such. It is a completely different product - not a new product revision.

Answer (score 1):

My tip: Besides packagist you can also search directly on **bitbucket** or **github** for *neos*.

If you understand german you can also find some tips on this blog: http://blog.dotpulse.ch/?s=neos

Comment: Yep. But there aren't many blogs out there with Neos Tips and Tricks. If you know some, just share it. On my "personal-to-do-list" is also a blog about Neos with some tutorials, but at the moment, I don't have enough time.

Comment: I'm just being difficult ;) However, it is considered good form to disclose your affiliations in your answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior  and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way